# Getter for a property set thru f:setPropertyActionListener not being called in primefaces Dialog

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a a button that is setting a property to a backing bean to be used in Primefaces Dialog.

```
p:commandButton value="Options" onclick="optionsDialog.show();">
`<f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{item}" target="#{bean.tempItem}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

I can see that setter is called here.

```
<p:dialog header="Options" widgetVar="OptionsDialog" dynamic="true" modal="true"
width="400" height="250">
<h:outputText value="#{bean.tempItem.value}"/> 
</p:dialog>
```

Here the getter is never called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the dialog's content is not been updated before you show it. You need to update it by `update` attribute of the command button. Reference the (relative) client ID of the dialog in there. You also need to replace `onclick` by `oncomplete` because the `onclick` fires *before* the action is performed and `oncomplete` fires *after* the action is performed.

```
<p:commandButton ... update="dialogId" oncomplete="optionsDialog.show();">

...

<p:dialog id="dialogId" ...>
```

You've by the way also a lowercase/uppercase typo in the dialog widget name. But that would cause the dialog to not show up at all, which is a different problem.

Comment: It's working but our button is in a data table. These buttons are available for each row in data table.When I click on button, the corresponding bean.tempItem id should pass to the dialog. It is working fine when i click on first time. After closing the dialog, it is not showing second time.

Comment: Which PrimeFaces version? Dialogs were troublesome in 3.0 betas and early versions. Only since 3.0.1 everything is right.

Comment: Hmm try removing `dynamic="true"`.